# Pointer aliasing of pointer containers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, containers, alias

I learned that pointer aliasing may hurt performance, and that a `__restrict__` attribute (in GCC, or equivalent attributes in other implementations) may help keeping track of which pointers should or should not be aliased. Meanwhile, I also learned that GCC's implementation of `valarray` stores a `__restrict__`'ed pointer (line 517 in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/valarray-source.html), which I think hints the compiler (and responsible users) that the private pointer can be assumed not to be aliased anywhere in `valarray` methods.

But if we alias a pointer to a `valarray` object, for example:

```
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    std::valarray<double> *a = new std::valarray<double>(10);
    std::valarray<double> *b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

is it valid to say that the member pointer of `a` is aliased too? And would the very existence of `b` hurt any optimizations that `valarray` methods could benefit otherwise? (Is it bad practice to point to optimized pointer containers?)

Comment: C++ doesn't have the `restrict` keyword. What you see in the valarray implementation is the GCC `__restrict__` extension.

Comment: @interjay, sorry, I was not very careful in my wording (I will edit the question accordingly). It is true that `restrict` is not a keyword of C++, but it is nonetheless supported by most compilers via a `__restrict__` attribute. My questions at the end, though, do not really depend on this fact (I just used it as a possible motivation for the question).

Comment: "and that a __restrict __ attribute helps keeping track" It does not. It *may* help keep track: compilers can totally ignore `restrict`.

Comment: @black, yes, I am totally aware of it. What I meant is that it helps the user keep track of what he/she should or should not do. Nothing prevents both the user or the compiler to ignore the hint. It has little to do with the question, though...

Comment: [This](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/sgi/audio/audio.apps/dev/aliasing.html) seems a nice place to get started. Is this what you want ?

Comment: `is it valid to say that the member pointer of a is aliased too?` No it is not. There's still only one `double*` pointer object pointing to the `valarray` data. `And would the very existence of b hurt any optimizations that valarray methods could benefit otherwise?` No. The effect of introducing aliasing where you originally promised the compiler there would be none is "the program exhibits undefined behavior", not "the compiler uses magic to go back in time and recompile functions without optimizations". In any case, again, your example doesn't alias in a way that violates the promise.

Comment: @Igor, but a->[0] and b->[0] are two different names for the same memory address, which by definition is aliasing. This is the reason for my question, and it was answered in a different way below...

Comment: `a->[0]` and `b->[0]` won't even compile. Anyway, `__restrict__` doesn't mean "no two expressions in the program can ever evaluate to this address". It means "you can assume that no other pointer object is used to access or modify data at this address". **That** is the definition of aliasing for the purposes of `__restrict__` specifier. It's OK for the pointer itself to be reachable multiple ways - just not the data it points to. Under your interpretation, you would never be able to call any method on `valarray`, because as soon as you do, it's reachable two ways - via `a` and via `this`.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that since `&a[0]` and `&b[0]` refer to the same address, then from @David's answer I understood that the pointer inside `valarray` is aliased by these two symbols. I could change the data at that address by doing, for example, `a[0]=1; b[0]=2;` and so on... but I see your point.

Comment: `__restrict__` restricts aliasing of the same location by different pointer *objects*, not different expressions referring to the same object. You are conflating two meanings of the term "alias" - name aliasing (e.g. "a reference introduces another name for the object it refers to, at compile time") and pointer aliasing ("two independent pointers point to the same location, at run time"). `__restrict__` is about the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand **how** aliasing hurts optimization.

Consider this code,

```
void
process_data(float *in, float *out, float gain, int nsamps)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < nsamps; i++) {
        out[i] = in[i] * gain;
    }
}
```

> In C or C++, it is legal for the parameters `in` and `out` to point to overlapping regions in memory.... When the compiler optimizes the function, it does not in general know whether `in` and `out` are aliases. It must therefore assume that any store through `out` can affect the memory pointed to by `in`, which severely limits its ability to reorder or parallelize the code (For some simple cases, the compiler could analyze the entire program to determine that two pointers cannot be aliases. But in general, it is impossible for the compiler to determine whether or not two pointers are aliases, so to be safe, it must assume that they are).

Coming to your code,

```
#include <valarray>

int main() {
    std::valarray<double> *a = new std::valarray<double>(10);
    std::valarray<double> *b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Since `a` and `b` are aliases. The underlying storage structure used by `valarray` will also be aliased(I think it uses an array. Not very sure about this). So, any part of your code that uses `a` and `b` in a fashion similar to that shown above will not benefit from compiler optimizations like parallelization and reordering. Note that JUST the existence of `b` will not hurt optimization but how you use it.

Credits:
The quoted part and the code is take from [here](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/sgi/audio/audio.apps/dev/aliasing.html). This should serve as a good source for more information about the topic as well.

Answer (score 0):

> is it valid to say that the member pointer of a is aliased too?

Yes. For example, `a->[0]` and `b->[0]` reference the same object. That's aliasing.

> And would the very existence of b hurt any optimizations that valarray methods could benefit otherwise?

No.

You haven't done anything with `b` in your sample code. Suppose you have a function much larger than this sample code that starts with the same construct. There's usually no problem if the first several lines of that function uses `a` but never `b`, and the remaining lines uses `b` but never `a`. Usually. (Optimizing compilers do rearrange lines of code however.)

If on the other hand you intermingle uses of `a` and `b`, you aren't hurting the optimizations. You are doing something much worse: You are invoking undefined behavior. "Don't do it" is the best solution to the undefined behavior problem.

**Addendum**

The C `restrict` and gcc `__restrict__` keywords are not constraints on the developers of the compiler or the standard library. Those keywords are promises to the compiler/library that restricted data do not overlap other data. The compiler/library doesn't check whether the programmer violated this promise. If this promise enables certain optimizations that might otherwise be invalid with overlapping data, the compiler/library is free to apply those optimizations.

What this means is that `restrict` (or `__restrict__`) is a restriction on you, not the compiler. You can violate those restrictions even without your `b` pointer. For example, consider

```
*a = a->[std::slice(a.size()-1,a.size(),-1)];
```

This is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you, @David, it is what I wanted to know. I just didn't understand what you mean about intermingling the use of the pointers, and how it leads to undefined behavior. I was convinced to follow the "don't do it" advice, though.

Comment: `a->[0]` and `b->[0]` are not valid expressions.

Comment: I believe you misrepresent what `__restrict__` does. Somewhere inside `valarray<T>`, there's a member `__restrict__ T* pData`. It doesn't matter that the same *pointer* can be accessed both as `a->pData` and `b->pData` - `__restrict__` only promises that the actual data at `*pData` cannot be accessed by another pointer, unrelated to `pData`. You, and the OP, are using the term "aliasing" in a very generic sense, while `__restrict__` assigns a specific meaning to it (one that takes 12 paragraphs to explain - see C99 **6.7.3.1**).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - You and I read those 12 paragraphs differently. (And a third party, differently yet. There are some who say that the meaning of the C `restrict` keyword is only defined for primitive types; e.g., see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3635.pdf).